# SQL Query GROUP BY with same values over multiple columns and return SUM of the relative time value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have pgAdmin 4.16.

The database contains a table called flights. In this table every row represents a flight. When a flight is delayed, the delay codes are used to describe the reason of the delay. Per delay code there is a time delay describing for how long the delay was. A delay can contain up to 3 delay codes with its relative delay time. I can group the delay codes per only 1 set of columns (delay code and delay time), but not over all 3 columns. Here is the script:

```
SELECT delay_code_1, COUNT(delay_code_1), AVG(delay_time_1), SUM(delay_time_1)
FROM flights
GROUP BY delay_code_1
ORDER BY SUM(delay_time_1) DESC
```

Here is the flights table:

[image]

Here is the desired result:

[image]

my sincere thanks

Comment: What is Postgres 4.16?

Comment: You select 4 columns, but expect only 2 in the result?!?

Comment: PostgreSQL 4? Are you sure?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about "pgAdmin 4.16"?

Comment: This database model is not 3NF. The query would be much easier if you normalised the database design.

Comment: The pgAdmin version is pretty much irrelevant. the Postgres version is interesting: `select version();`

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because the table is not in normal form - repeating groups should be broken out into another table.  If this is your schema, you might redisign.

But, assuming you cannot change the schema, one solution would be to union three passes at the table, e.g.

```
SELECT delay_code, SUM(delay_time) as Total_Time
FROM
(
SELECT delay_code_1 as delay_code, delay_time_1 as delay_time
FROM flight
WHERE delay_code_1 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT delay_code_2 as delay_code, delay_time_2 as delay_time
FROM flight
WHERE delay_code_2 is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT delay_code_3 as delay_code, delay_time_3 as delay_time
FROM flight
WHERE delay_code_3 is not null
)
GROUP BY delay_code
```

HTH

---

EDITED - as mentioned by @a_horse_with_no_name, UNION ALL should be used here.  Plain UNION de-dupes the results, so Total_Time would be wrong if there were multiple delays of the same code and time.

Comment: Many thanks for your Answer, it works perfect. My hat off. Forgive my ignorance, my I ask why this table is not in normal form? How would repeating groups look like?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You are absolutely right, Don't know what was I thinking about.

Comment: @KenOn10: `union all` would be more efficient than a `union` here

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i'm not sure about efficiency here, but `UNION ALL` will give the proper result.  good catch.

Comment: @KenOn10: it **will** be more efficient because `UNION` tries to remove duplicates which `UNION ALL` does not. But I think UNION ALL is actually the correct thing to use anyway because duplicate combinations of code/delay_time should be included